# React Recharts: Design custom tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, recharts

I am trying to replace `recharts` default tooltip with custom tooltip.

The existing tooltip looks like this.

[image]

I wanted to replace the above default tooltip as

[image]

I made [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-jasper-zc4v7s?file=/src/App.js) for the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very quick solution. You can alter it as you want

Create a custom tooltip class

```
export const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
  if (active && payload && payload.length) {
    return (
      <div className="custom-tooltip">
        <p className="label">{`${label} : ${payload[0].value}`}</p>
        <div>
          {payload.map((pld) => (
            <div style={{ display: "inline-block", padding: 10 }}>
              <div style={{ color: pld.fill }}>{pld.value}</div>
              <div>{pld.dataKey}</div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```

And use it like this

```
<Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} cursor={{ fill: "transparent" }} />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-napier-pzbdld?)

Comment: Thankyou so much! I will do the rest styling. Appreciate it.

Comment: I'm using typescript. What are the types of active,payload and label?